# How to decrypt files from SD card on android phone?

Tags: encryption

sorry if this is a repost. I am using a  Gionee P5L with Android 5.1. This system allows files on the SD card (mounted in the phone) to be encrypted. The whole SD card is not encrypted. And it does not ask for password to encrypt a file. If I hold my finger on a file name in the explorer, some menu appears at the bottom of the screen. The last one is "more".  Under the "more" option there are other options,  and the first one being "encrypt". If I select that, no password is asked,  and the file disappears from the explorer. My question is, is there any way I can get it back?

Comment: Their should be an option to open the secure storage directory... sorry I'm not sure what explorer you are using !